# Detect if action bar item is in overflow menu or actually displayed on action bar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, overflow-menu

This is one of my items of actionbar -

```
<item
        android:id="@+id/mode"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_ring_volume"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="@string/Ringing_Mode"/>
```

Here i am using ifRoom in showAsAction . Now it may or may not show on action bar according to the space available. How can i detect if it's showing in overflow menu or its actually displayed on action bar ? (I am not using ActionBarSherlock)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **ActionBarSherlock** you can look for the boolean value `abs__split_action_bar_is_narrow`

Create static method where you can do

```
return ResourcesCompat.getResources_getBoolean(context,
                            R.bool.abs__split_action_bar_is_narrow);
```

you need to use the ResourcesCompat (from actionbarsherlock) class.

This will Provide you,if it's showing in overflow menu or its actually displayed on action bar.

Comment: I am not using ActionBarSherlock. So any way of doing this for ActionBarCompat ?

Comment: @KrupaPatel: Why are you providing two answers? Either, edit this answer or remove the other.